# SQL Server query JSONobject to get aggregated values

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a JSON object stored in SQL Server, in a `nvarchar(max)` column. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
"data": [{
        "RespID": 3512,
        "ObsPriceValue": 2.34
    }, {
        "RespID": 4904,
        "ObsPriceValue": 2.54
    }, {
        "RespID": 5127,
        "ObsPriceValue": 3.44
    }]
}
```

The above example array is made up of three items, but I don't know how many items are present in the record, and they can be 2 as well as up to 30.

Each row in the table has an object like the above.

I'd like to get, in a single query, the average value of the field ObsPriceValue

I've tried with `JSON_QUERY`, but I have always to specify the index of the element.

Is there a way to get it or the JSON schema the data is stored is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next approach may help. You need to use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema definition to return a table with `ObsPriceValue` column:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"data": [{
        "RespID": 3512,
        "ObsPriceValue": 2.34
    }, {
        "RespID": 4904,
        "ObsPriceValue": 2.54
    }, {
        "RespID": 5127,
        "ObsPriceValue": 3.44
    }]
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT AVG(ObsPriceValue) AS AvgObsPriceValue
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.data') WITH (
   ObsPriceValue numeric(10, 2) '$.ObsPriceValue' 
) j
```

Output:

```
----------------
AvgObsPriceValue
----------------
2.773333
```

Comment: So this is the only way with the JSON data stored in that way? There could be other possible way to store the data in order to simplify the SQL query? (Even if it seems perfect to me)

Comment: @Giox Yes, I think so. When you have a JSON array, use OPENJSON to parse this array.